# Woocommerce-admin extension: changes to js/index.js have no effect

Tags: javascript, wordpress, npm, woocommerce, backend

I am trying to write an extension for woocommerce-admin analytics. I have installed an example extension and it runs fine. But any changes I make to its *js/index.js* are not reflected in the browser.

**Details:**

I installed woocommerce-admin as described here:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin

I then installed the *add-report* extension as described here:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/tree/main/docs/examples/extensions

The example extension works fine when I look at http://localhost/wp-admin

The Woocommerce Dev Docs say "You can make changes to Javascript and PHP files in the example and see changes reflected upon refresh", but when I modify *add-report/js/index.js* nothing changes in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer: I should have been editing the js file in the main *woocommerce-admin/* folder, not the js file in the new *add-report/* plugin folder.

Changes to */wp-content/plugins/add-report/src/index.js* are ignored, and have **no effect in the browser :-(**

Changes to */wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-admin/docs/examples/extensions/add-report/src/index.js* are built successfully, and **have an effect in the browser :-)**